# Não consigo executar uma query com jdbc java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, java-8

```
public List<Sistema> buscarUsuarioSistemaPor(Long cpf) throws SQLException {
    List<Sistema> listSistemas = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql = "select s.* from sistema as s\r\n" + 
            "inner join usuariosistema as u on (u.idsistema = s.idsistema)\r\n" + 
            "where u.usuario_cpf = @cpf";
    connect();

    PreparedStatement prepareStatement = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepareStatement.setLong(1, cpf);

    ResultSet resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Long idSistema = resultSet.getLong("idSistema");
        String nome = resultSet.getString("Nome");

        Sistema Sistema = new Sistema(idSistema, nome);

        listSistemas.add(Sistema);
    }

    resultSet.close();
    prepareStatement.close();

    disconnect();

    return listSistemas;
}
```

O seguinte erro está ocorrendo: 
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

estou usando a versão do conector mysql:

> Citação

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Fazendo com o parametro na query dessa outra forma:

```
public List<Sistema> buscarUsuarioSistemaPor(Long cpf) throws SQLException {
    List<Sistema> listSistemas = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql = "select s.* from sistema as s\r\n" + 
            "inner join usuariosistema as u on (u.idsistema = s.idsistema)\r\n" + 
            "where u.usuario_cpf = ?";
    connect();

    PreparedStatement prepareStatement = jdbcConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
    prepareStatement.setLong(1, cpf);

    ResultSet resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery(sql);

    while (resultSet.next()) {
        Long idSistema = resultSet.getLong("idSistema");
        String nome = resultSet.getString("Nome");

        Sistema Sistema = new Sistema(idSistema, nome);

        listSistemas.add(Sistema);
    }

    resultSet.close();
    prepareStatement.close();

    disconnect();

    return listSistemas;
}
```

> Ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 3
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1218)
at br.com.sefaz.dao.Usuario_SistemaDAO.buscarUsuarioSistemaPor(Usuario_SistemaDAO.java:101)
at br.com.sefaz.controller.Usuario_SistemaController.buscarUsuarioSistemaPor(Usuario_SistemaController.java:37)
at br.com.sefaz.dao.UsuarioDAO.listAllUsuarios(UsuarioDAO.java:100)
at br.com.sefaz.controller.UsuarioController.listAllUsuarios(UsuarioController.java:52)
at br.com.sefaz.main.Teste.main(Teste.java:35)
```

> Já não sei mais o que fazer, alguém me ajude por favor?

Comment: Não tem muito sentido estes \r\n em sua sentença SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo altere seu código

```
ResultSet resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Para

```
ResultSet resultSet = prepareStatement.executeQuery();
```

Não precisa passar a query como parâmetro do executeQuery quando se esta chamando ele pela PrepareStatement. Na sua preparestatement você já informou o select, não precisa passar novamente.

**[Editado]**
Encontrei a documentação onde fala disso: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)

Comment: Obrigado cara, tava tão bitolado no problema que não vi que tinha colocado 2x o sql. Sua recomendação resolveu meu problema.

Comment: Que bom, fico feliz que tenha resolvido. Se deu certo, por favor marque a resposta como correta para ajudar outras pessoas que procurarem por este erro.

Comment: Ja tinha marcado.

Comment: Verdade, me desculpe na hora que escrevi o comentário  não tinha percebido. Mas acho que foi tentar marcar de novo e agora desmarcou a resposta como correta rssrs

Answer (score 0):

`select s.* from sistema as`      <--- você precisa  colocar a mesma referência aonde vc colocou ( `s.*` ) Revise os espaços da SQL.

```
String sql = "select s.* from sistema as s\r\n" + 
        "inner join usuariosistema as u on (u.idsistema = s.idsistema)\r\n" + 
        "where u.usuario_cpf = @cpf";
```

Tenta fazer separado que irá lhe ajudar muito usei

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(); 
sql.append(" SELECT * FROM TABELA "):
sql.append(" WHERE ID = ?");

sql.toString;
```